# Non serializable function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, bytebuffer

So, I am tasked to write a code that memory maps rdd data to shared memory:

```
data: RDD[Vector]) // parametr to function

// local variables
val file: RandomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("/tmp/test.txt", "rw");
val out: MappedByteBuffer = file.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 60000);

data.foreach(a => {
      val arr = a.toArray; // this is type Array[Double]
      val o: MappedByteBuffer = out;
      val bbuf = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(8*arr.length) // represent array of double as byte buffer
      bbuf.asDoubleBuffer.put(java.nio.DoubleBuffer.wrap(arr)) // add to bytebuffer
      o.put(bbuf);
    });
```

Now, the issue is that ByteBuffer is non-serializable and I don't know how to serialize it. I can maybe try some different way to append double array to buffer, but as long as the function is non-serializable I keep getting error. I suspect .put() would also create error after the first is solved. How do I go forward with this.

Comment: I would not reinvent writing an RDD to a file, especially it won't work with local files, you need HDFS or other distributed storage files and **Spark** already provides ways to do that.

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. Thanks for response. Our research lab developed a accelerator, coded in C. We want to evaluate whether we can improve map reduce by "doing" x % on CPU (implemented in Spark) and "100 - x %" in new accelerator. So I have to share partial memory in MapReduce, so that it can be offloaded (to code written in C and ultimately to accelerator).

Comment: So you really want parallel processing and not distributed one? I would say it would be better to do that using a **Streaming** solution _(like `fs2`)_ instead of **Spark**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think what I would like to have is something like this: there is 10000 data points distributed for map reduce at 5 nodes (2000 each?).  Now at each of this node, I want 1000 to be done as usual on cpu and 1000 to be offloaded to accelerator. In the code, of I do .collect().foreach it works but it would bring all 10000 datapoint. only .foreach would iterate over 2000 points but it is not working because of serializable issue...

Comment: Maybe you wan to use `mapPartitions` instead and open the file for each partition.